# Check Box and ListBox C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to print something in a Listbox? The main ideia is to check a CheckBox and than print in the list.
Per example there's a CheckBox that's write "C#" and checking shows in the ListBox "C#".

I already tried to use in the ListBox:

```
private void listbox_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
if(cbCSharp.Checked)
   {

     lbCursos.Items.Add(cbCSharp.Text);

   }
  
}
```

PS: listbox = ListBox
cbCSharp = CheckBox - C#

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should use the CheckBox's CheckedChanged event instead of the ListBox's SelectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the code within the if block to the CheckedChanged event on your "cbCSharp" checkbox, then that ought to achieve what you're looking for. Right now, as you have it defined, when you change the currently selected item in your list box, only then would another list box item get created on the list box with the value of cbCSharp.Text.